# Big mysql query versus an http post connection in terms of long term speed

Tags: python, mysql, django

right now I think i'm stuck between two main choices for grabbing a user's friends list.

The first is a direct connection with facebook, and the pulling the friends list out and creating a list of friend models with the json. (Takes quite a while whenever I try it out, like 2 seconds?)

The other is whenever a user logs in, the program will store his or her entire friends list inside a big friends model (note that even if two people have the same exact friends, two sets will still be stored, all friend models will have an FK back to the person who has these friends on their list).

Whenever a user needs his or her friends list, I just use django's filter to grab them.
Right now this is pretty fast but that's because it hasn't been tested with many people yet.

Based off of your guys experience, which of these two decisions would make the most sense long term?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on what you plan on doing with the data. However, thinking long term you're going to have *much* more flexibility with breaking out the friends into distinct units than just storing them all together.

If the friend creation process is taking too long, you should consider off-loading it to a separate process that can finish it in the background, using something like Celery.